# deleting Flask memory cache

Tags: python, caching, flask

I have a web app that starts like this:

```
#It starts here
@app.route('/game')
def game():
```

Inside `game`, it dynamically builds an image with `PIL` and saves it to `/static/testing_image.png`

It then renders a template.

```
return render_template('game.html',
                           file_name=file_name,
                           image_width=SQ_SIZE,
                           sleep_time=1000
                           )
```

Now, inside `game.html`, what happens is that I wait for `sleep_time`ms and then I want to go call `game` again, so that a **new image is built and displayed**.

The code below waits until the image is fully loaded, it displays it, waits, and redirects.

```
function LoadImage() {
     var img = new Image(),
      x = document.getElementById("image");

    img.onload = function() {
        x.src = img.src;
        var sleep_time={{sleep_time}};
        setTimeout(function(){
            //I REDIRECT HERE
            window.location="{{url_for('game')}}";
         }, sleep_time);

     };

    img.src="{{url_for('static', filename=file_name)  }}";
}
```

**THE PROBLEM**

The issue is of course that the image is served from memory cache, and even though the underlying file, `/static/testing_image.png`, **has** been updated, flask does not get the new one.

[image]

You can see in the below how `testing_image.png` is served from the cache.

My question is two-fold.

1. Should I be doing this in a different way?
2. If not, how can I force flask to do a hard reload on the image?

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a better way to structure this, but it's hard to say without looking at the rest of your code.  As far as busting the cache, you should be able to use this:

[http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/40/](http://web.archive.org/web/20190128051357/http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/40/)

Comment: Well, it's essentially a template that calls itself. I just want to make the calls after the first one behave exactly like the first call, without saving anything on cache.